# Use node.js to forward url to a gaming server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, forward, game-development

So my goal is to have node.js forward a specific url to an external server hosting a minecraft server.

First of all, how could I go about doing this? When trying to find a means to do this all I can seem to come up with in search results is how to setup node.js server for developing a game, or I find how to forward from one port to another on the same machine.

Secondly, concerning means of doing this, hoping I can do so in a method where the client now goes back and forth directly with the server rather than routing all data through the node.js server. The goal here isn't to obscure the server, just to provide an easier to remember url for the server. Mind you if that's not possible I'll just route it all through the server and see in time if there are any issues with such.

Edit for clarity:

I have a website setup using node.js at mydomain.com, it's a fairly simple setup, I'd like mydomain.com/mine to redirect to a minecraft server hosted by a different company.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question and what you're actually trying to do.  But my guess is you're trying to send some http request.  Try taking a look at the [request project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).  Or from your second question, it sounds like you want to do a reverse proxy, which you would setup on your server.  Try searching for reverse proxy, there's a bunch of option but personally I use Nginx or Apache

Comment: Tried to clarify in an edit, reverse proxy at first glance looks to be a solution, not ideal since it seems to route all data through the web server, but could be worse. I don't think request project will do what I am looking for but I could be mistaken there.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah for that use case you can just set the response to a 301 and use the location keyword.  I'll submit an example as an answer in a minute

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to solve this problem would involve creating an "A" record for your domain in your DNS panel on your web host. With an A record, you would have something like minecraft.mydomain.com redirect to your server's ip. Here's some information about A records: http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/spry_menu/a-record/

Googling around about domain redirects to game servers makes me believe this should work, but I haven't done it myself.

Comment: That definitely will work, however I tend to run test servers or initially run servers locally on a non-static ip address where this wouldn't be ideal. Which is why I am looking for a node.js solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to do a simple redirect.

Assuming your app is itself a node.js app, Here's a quick example redirecting my localhost:9000 to google.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(301, {Location: 'http://google.com'});
  response.end();
});

server.listen(9000);

console.log("http://127.0.0.1:9000/");
```

Comment: Ahh, alright, didn't think minecraft would take a simple redirect like that, will test later tonight and check back in on this, thank you.

Comment: So unfortunately this does not work, in my testing I have not been able to get any node.js code to trigger when attempting to connect to it via minecraft.